# how to stop selenium c# overwriting textbox after clicking add button?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a textbox. when I click the "ADD" button I sendkeys to textbox and I would like to add an another line, so I click "ADD" button again, but it's adding an another text box to enter the value, but it always overwrite the first line.
// Clicking Add Line button
            // ngDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[1]/div[3]/form/div/fieldset[2]/div/div[4]/button")).Click();

```
        // Selecting Item from dropdown

        //  SelectElement se3 = new SelectElement(ngDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model("line")));
        // se3.SelectByValue("string:A");
```

Comment: It seems you are not writing proper xpath. Could you please share the html code and share screenshot to explain your requirement properly?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. Sorry I can't share screenshot. Everytime I click the "Add" button, a new text box will be added to add items. for example - I added a "Item 1" and then I click "Add" button and that 'll will bring a new text box to add "Item 2". But Instead "Item1" will be replaced by "Item 2".

Comment: If you write your xpath with the default value from the browser your automation will break constantly. 1 change by a dev adding in a div tag in that area kills it. You should review https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

Suppose consider a division is there in that text box and add button are available.

Assuming that i need to click on add button 2 times, then try the following code

```
IWebElement division = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='form-info']"));

division.FindElement(By.TagName("input")).SendKeys("text to enter");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
     division.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();
     Thread.Sleep(2000);
     division = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='form-info']"));
     Thread.Sleep(2000);
     division.FindElements(By.TagName("input"))[i+1].SendKeys("text to enter");
}
```

Change this as per your Xpath structure. This is just an example. Because with out seeing Xpath, it is not that easy to explain what you are expected